# How do I load the jsp pages using Spring MVC framework for a Spring Boot application? I get null pointer exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jsp, spring-boot

I always get a null pointer exception when my code attempts to look and load for jsp pages. This is for a Spring Boot app and I am trying to use latest Spring MVC framework. Note, I am deploying the app in a jar not as a war file. 
So there are no WEB-APP folders or web.xml etc on my project.
 I have folder "templates" under src/main/resources where ViewName.jsp page is placed.

 Here is code snippet for your reference from my Controller java file:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/x")
public String launch(@RequestParam("inputFile") String inputFile, @RequestParam("instance") int instance) {

    try {
        launcher.launch(inputFile, instance);
        LOGGER.info("launch completed, trying to set and load the view now");

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        LOGGER.error("Failed to launch job successfully.", ex);
    }

    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();

    Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<>();

    parameters.put("inputFile", inputFile);
    parameters.put("instance", Integer.toString(instance));
    mav.addObject("parameters", parameters);

    LOGGER.info("Before setting mav.setViewname");

    mav.setViewName("ViewName");

    LOGGER.info("After setting mav.setViewname, that means setViewName is good"); //this gets printed in the log

    return "ViewName.jsp";


}
```

Below is the null pointer exception thrown:

> ERROR: org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter - Forwarding to error page from request [/x] due to exception [null]
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: null
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletResponseImpl.sendContentError(ServletResponseImpl.java:713) ~[weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletResponseImpl.sendError(ServletResponseImpl.java:761) ~[weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletResponseImpl.sendError(ServletResponseImpl.java:693) ~[weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
>       at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter$ErrorWrapperResponse.flushBuffer(ErrorPageFilter.java:315) ~[spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.forward(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:321) ~[weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:168) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1286) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1041) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:984) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731) ~[weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:844) ~[weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:280) ~[weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:254) ~[weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:136) ~[weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:346) ~[weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25) ~[weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79) ~[weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
>       at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:115) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:59) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:90) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:108) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79) [weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
>       at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:106) [spring-boot-actuator-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79) [weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) [spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79) [weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) [spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79) [weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:108) [spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79) [weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79) [weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
>       at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:110) [spring-boot-actuator-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79) [weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
>       at org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79) [weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3451) [weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3417) [weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
>       at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321) [weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
>       at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120) [com.oracle.css.weblogic.security.wls_7.1.0.0.jar:CSS 7.1 0.0]
>       at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57) [weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2280) [weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2196) [weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2174) [weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1632) [weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
>       at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:256) [weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
>       at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311) [weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
>       at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263) [weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]

Comment: See: https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/. You don't have to return a `jsp` prefix  "ViewName.jsp" should be  "ViewName".

Comment: Thanks Anton. I have removed the .jsp and going to redeploy the app. I will let you know it goes.

Comment: Anton, I got the same exception at the same step after removing .jsp. Not sure what am I missing, I followed the guide that you shared as well.

Comment: I don't think its even looking for any view at src/main/resources/templates folder. I tried to look and load for ViewName and under templates I have had ViewName.html - Still I get the same exception.

Comment: Your whole `ModelAndView` is useless. You are returning a `String` so there is nothing in the model (as the `ModelAndView` is only used inside the method). Instead return the `ModelAndView` instead of the name of the view. Next to that I would strongly suggest NOT to use JPS but rather something like Thymeleaf.

Comment: You are absly right! Thanks for your valuable comment. It made a lot of sense. I made the suggested changes i.e. returning ModelandView object instead of string and load HTML pages. It worked successfully.  I couldn't find option to mark your answer as the best so I upvoted your comment. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, spring boot does not support any jsp files from classpath. 
There are two solutions, 
1. You can put Thymeleaf template in classpath. Spring boot will automatically configure it.
2. If you want to load JSP template, then you should put jsp files under src/main/webapp. InternalResourceViewResolver will configure it.

Comment: Thank you Rashed, you are right. I followed Solution 1 and used Thymeleaf to load .html pages instead of jsp with the recommended folder structure .

Answer (score 1):

By default spring boot doesn't support JSPs so you need to add the support like below.

add tomcat jasper dependency in your `pom.xml`

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-jasper -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-jasper</artifactId>
    <version>8.5.31</version>
</dependency>
```

**Here `version` should be same which your spring boot internal tomcat uses(for me it was 8.5.31)

by adding this dependency spring boot will get to know that how to convert a jsp into servlet.

The jsp page should be inside webapp directory. i am attaching an image for your reference regarding directory structure and video link for step by step configuration.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLbvzF1-vXY

[image: Project Directory Structure]

Comment: Thanks Alien, I tried not to load JSPs and I used Thymeleaf to load HTML pages instead with dynamic loading of the variables. It worked for me.

Comment: That nice decision...but my answer works well for JSP.

Comment: I am sure it will!